# PHP Compare 2 Arrays - array to string conversion error

Tags: php, arrays, class

```
    foreach($this->galleryPhotoDBInitialArray as $initialArrayElement) {
        $photoExists = false;
         foreach($this->galleryPhotoDBFinalArray as $finalArrayElement) {
            if($initialArrayElement == $finalArrayElement) {
              $photoExists = true;
                echo $initialArrayElement;
            }
        }
        if(!$photoExists){
            echo 'delete............................................';
            echo $initialArrayElement;
        }
    }
```

I have the above code. I know the arrays have data as I can print_r() it and see the data. the Array data looks like this:

[image]

What do I need to do so I can access the $initialArrayElement value - I need to process this further but I get the PHP error 'array to string conversion error'...

thankyou very much :)

Comment: Seems like you're trying to `echo` an array, which gives that warning. Use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` instead.

Comment: you mean I have an array of arrays... ok

Comment: ok I understand now... array of arrays - got it working... thanks for you comment above - it helped me understand... just learning... cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $initialArrayElement;
```

use print_r on this and check if this is still an array.. because at what i observe this was still an array..

Answer (score 0):

Please use

`print_r($initialArrayElement);` insted of `echo $initialArrayElement;`

that will work.